# Meaning of Earth gravity for patents based or related to it

Tags: change

Mostly, patents assume normal gravity condition.

Imagine a device which would not work upfront in low or absent gravity.

Would a modified device but working for same purpose and all other considered physical principles not changed, so modification has been done just to support changed gravity condition.

Is this worth of a new patent or is there still a dependency (because of same general idea) or even infringement?

Answer (score 2):

All inventions must be new, useful and non-obvious to be patented.  I suppose new can be assumed, and useful would be likely met. The major factor that would matter in this case is obviousness to a person having ordinary skill in the art per 35 U.S.C. 103.  If it is easily and accurately predictable such as using a spring with a different spring constant then you will likely be denied.  If there are unexpected results that require experimentation to resolve a useful answer such as containing particulates in zero gravity, then you are more likely to be granted a patent.

Comment: Think about all the special toilets, food storage and water recycling on the space station. All of that requires special design.

Comment: A very good answer, but the question specifically asked about the worth of a patent. This implies to me economic value. If there is a very limited market, then it might not be worth pursuing a patent even if the invention qualifies for a patent.

Comment: @EricShain, I believe he meant "worthy" which would make the answer appropriate.

Comment: Perhaps you are right. People should, however consider the commercial viability of patents.